# blazor server app Auth problem with adding token

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have problem with blazor server app
I am using HttpClient in startup.cs and I want to add token as a header before api request.

```
   [Inject]
    public FKSERVICES fKSERVICES { get;  }
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddRazorPages();
        services.AddServerSideBlazor();
        services.AddSingleton<WeatherForecastService>();
        services.AddSingleton<FKSERVICES>();
        services.AddScoped<IAuthenticationService, AuthenticationService>();
        services.AddHttpClient<IHttpService, HttpService>();
        services.AddHttpClient<ILocalStorageService, LocalStorageService>();
        services.AddHttpClient<ICategoryService, CategoryService>(client => {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:5001/");
            string tokenVal = fKSERVICES.GetToken();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", tokenVal);

        });
    }
```

I tried so many way to do that but i always get the same error even when i create new class with simple method the same error come
this is the FKSERVICES service that i create to test if i can get value from other class

```
 public class FKSERVICES
{
    public FKSERVICES()
    {
    }
    public string GetToken()
    {
        return "";

    }
}
```

this is the error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BygRk.png)

Please help me

Comment: Are you sure `[Inject] public FKSERVICES fKSERVICES` is not null?

Comment: You need to use a different overload for `.AddHttpClient` that accepts `IServiceProvider`, then resolve `FKServices` from it.

Comment: @abdusco thnx can u give me an example ?

Answer (score 0):

If you set a break point in the `AddHttpClient` method and check the `fKSERVICES`, you can see it is `Null`, because you didn't create an instance or set the value for it.

To get the token, you could modify the AddHttpClient method as below:

```
services.AddHttpClient<ICategoryService, CategoryService>(client =>
{
    #pragma warning disable ASP0000 // Do not call 'IServiceCollection.BuildServiceProvider' in 'ConfigureServices'
    var sp = services.BuildServiceProvider();
    #pragma warning restore ASP0000 // Do not call 'IServiceCollection.BuildServiceProvider' in 'ConfigureServices'
    var kservice = sp.GetRequiredService<FKSERVICES>();
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:5001/");
    string tokenVal = kservice.GetToken();
    
   // client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", tokenVal);

});
```

The result as below (in the FKSERVICES.GetToken method, I will return a string: "FKSERVICES Token"):

[image]